# Setting pandas.DataFrame string dtype (not file based)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm having trouble with using `pandas.DataFrame`'s constructor and using the `dtype` argument. I'd like to preserve string values, but the following snippets always convert to a numeric type and then yield `NaN`s.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def main():
    columns = ['great', 'good', 'average', 'bad', 'horrible']
    # minimal example, dates are coming (as strings) from some
    # non-file source.
    example_data = {
        'alice': ['', '', '', '2016-05-24', ''],
        'bob': ['', '2015-01-02', '', '', '2012-09-15'],
        'eve': ['2011-12-31', '', '1998-08-13', '', ''],
    }

    # first pass, yields dataframe full of NaNs
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=example_data, index=example_data.keys(),
        columns=columns, dtype=str) #or string, 'str', 'string', 'object'
    print(df.dtypes)
    print(df)
    print()

    # based on https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py
    # and https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/37f95cef85834207db0930e863341efb285e38a2/pandas/types/common.py
    # we're ultimately feeding dtype to numpy's dtype, so let's just use that:
    #     (using np.dtype('S10') and converting to str doesn't work either)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=example_data, index=example_data.keys(),
        columns=columns, dtype=np.dtype('U'))
    print(df.dtypes)
    print(df) # still full of NaNs... =(



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What value(s) of `dtypes` will preserve strings in the data frame?

for reference:

> $ python --version
>
> 2.7.12
>
> $ pip2 list | grep pandas
>
> pandas (0.18.1)
>
> $ pip2 list | grep numpy
>
> numpy (1.11.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the particular case in the OP, you can use the [`DataFrame.from_dict()` constructor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) (see also the [Alternate Constructors](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#alternate-constructors) section of the DataFrame documentation) .

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function

import pandas as pd

columns = ['great', 'good', 'average', 'bad', 'horrible']
example_data = {
    'alice': ['', '', '', '2016-05-24', ''],
    'bob': ['', '2015-01-02', '', '', '2012-09-15'],
    'eve': ['2011-12-31', '', '1998-08-13', '', ''],
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(example_data, orient='index')
df.columns = columns

print(df.dtypes)
# great       object
# good        object
# average     object
# bad         object
# horrible    object
# dtype: object

print(df)
#             great        good     average         bad    horrible
# bob                2015-01-02                          2012-09-15
# eve    2011-12-31              1998-08-13                        
# alice                                      2016-05-24
```

You can even specify `dtype=str` in `DataFrame.from_dict()` — though it is not necessary in this example.

EDIT: The DataFrame constructor interprets a dictionary as a collection of columns:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(example_data))

#         alice         bob         eve
# 0                          2011-12-31
# 1              2015-01-02            
# 2                          1998-08-13
# 3  2016-05-24                        
# 4              2012-09-15
```

(I'm dropping the `data=`, since `data` is the first argument in the function's signature anyway). Your code confuses rows and columns:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(example_data, index=example_data.keys(), columns=columns))

#       great good average  bad horrible
# alice   NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN      NaN
# bob     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN      NaN
# eve     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN      NaN
```

(though I'm not exactly sure how it ends up giving you a DataFrame of `NaN`s). It would be correct to do

```
print(pd.DataFrame(example_data, columns=example_data.keys(), index=columns))

#                alice         bob         eve
# great                             2011-12-31
# good                  2015-01-02            
# average                           1998-08-13
# bad       2016-05-24                        
# horrible              2012-09-15
```

Specifying the column names is actually unnecessary — they are already parsed from the dictionary:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(example_data, index=columns))

#                alice         bob         eve
# great                             2011-12-31
# good                  2015-01-02            
# average                           1998-08-13
# bad       2016-05-24                        
# horrible              2012-09-15
```

What you want is actually the *transpose* of this — so you can also take said transpose!

```
print(pd.DataFrame(data=example_data, index=columns).T)

#             great        good     average         bad    horrible
# alice                                      2016-05-24            
# bob                2015-01-02                          2012-09-15
# eve    2011-12-31              1998-08-13
```

Comment: Yay, this works. Out of curiosity, do you know why this works while the original doesn't? Given the usual constructor can take dictionaries it's not clear to me why the `from_dict` constructor behaves so differently.

Comment: @everial: after looking at it more carefully, I figured out what it is that you were doing wrong --- see edit.

Comment: thanks for the detailed followup... you can see how experience with pandas I am. =)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper answer, but while you get one by someone else, I've noticed that using the `read_csv` function everything works.

So if you place your data in a `.csv` file called `myData.csv`, like this:

```
great,good,average,bad,horrible
alice,,,,2016-05-24,
bob,,2015-01-02,,,2012-09-15
eve,2011-12-31,,1998-08-13,,
```

and do

```
df = pd.read_csv('blablah/myData.csv')
```

it will keep the strings as they are!

```
        great      good     average       bad      horrible
alice    NaN        NaN       NaN     2016-05-24      NaN
bob      NaN    2015-01-02    NaN         NaN     2012-09-15
eve   2011-12-31    NaN    1998-08-13     NaN         NaN
```

if you want, the empty values can be put as an space in the csv file or any other character/marker.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as mentioned in the sample the data currently isn't in a file -- I don't really want to write it out just to reread it with `read_csv` if that can be avoided.